# WPF - Popup Menu on MouseDown, then select with MouseUp

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, menu, radial

I am trying to create a UserControl that behaves like so:

- A button to start with, and when a user clicks it and holds, a Radial menu appears
- User keeps holding left mouse, and releases on the menu item they want
- I am using this Radial menu https://github.com/Julien-Marcou/RadialMenu

Here is my attempt:

```
<UserControl x:Class="NetBoard.RadialButton"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NetBoard"
             xmlns:radial="clr-namespace:RadialMenu.Controls;assembly=RadialMenu"
             mc:Ignorable="d" >
    <Grid>
        <Button Name="Button"
                PreviewMouseDown="Button_MouseDown" 
                PreviewMouseUp="Button_MouseUp" />

        <radial:RadialMenu Name="RadialMenu" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

```
public partial class RadialButton : UserControl
{
    public RadialButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Test menu items
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            RadialMenu.Content.Add(new RadialMenuItem { Content = i });
        }

        foreach (RadialMenuItem item in RadialMenu.Content)
        {
            item.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp += Slice_MouseUp;
        }
    }

    private void Button_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        RadialMenu.IsOpen = true;
    }

    private void Button_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        RadialMenu.IsOpen = false;
    }

    private void Slice_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("It worked!");
    }
```

The radial menu pops up fine, but the PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp event does not fire on the RadialMenuItems. The Menu Items don't even behave like they are being moused-over (they would change color).

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Sounds like you need to contact the author of the `RadialMenu` class you're using. You're asking a lot, expecting the Stack Overflow community to download a third-party library and diagnose your problem with it. As a guess, it seems likely you're running into an issue with mouse capture, where something else is getting mouse events exclusively, preventing your menu items from seeing anything. But presumably the author of the `RadialMenu` class has some intended mechanism for selecting menu items.

Comment: I was bored, and intrigued by the radial control. Your code, works just fine in the solution I made. So my guess is that your issue lies elsewhere. You said that the mouseover states do not work. Do you perhaps have a transparent control being rendered over the radial menu?

Answer (score 0):

I actually got this working using a Label instead of a button.